# Spring Boot - Ehcache Second Level Cache Integration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching

I am trying to hold some variables in the second level cache. I have read and applied the [instructions in Baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache). However, it keeps giving this error:

*Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory.buildTimestampsRegion(NoCachingRegionFactory.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache.(UpdateTimestampsCache.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.(CacheImpl.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.getService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)*

I added this dependency to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, added these lines to application.properties:

```
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

At the top of the entity classes, I added these caching annotations:

```
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
```

In the configuration file, I added ***@EnableCaching*** annotation.

Here are other beans and methods I added to configuration file:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name")));
    dataSource.setUrl(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url")));
    dataSource.setUsername(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username")));
    dataSource.setPassword(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password")));

    return dataSource;
}

final Properties additionalProperties() {
    final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache"));
    return hibernateProperties;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Is there something wrong with the configuration methods?
**Note**: This is a spring-boot project.

Comment: If this is a spring boot project why are you trying so hard not to use it? Why all the manual configuration? Remove it and prefix your specifiek hibernate properties with `spring.jpa.properties`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @M.Deinum. As you said I removed the methods from CoreConfig. I added these lines to application.properties file:

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory

The project can be built now, however, when it comes to the line I fetch from DB, it throws NestedServletException exception.